# Icons on view toolbar don't respond

Tags: delphi, ide, toolbar, delphi-10.4-sydney

The icons on the View toolbar no longer work.
If I click them they change color but no dialog opens, or the visibility of non-visual components doesn't switch.

[image]

This is Delphi 10.4 Update 1. IIRC it did not happen with the update, but later.
I tried dragging it around, hiding it, in combination with 'Save Desktop', reboots, all without success.

Other info:

- It also happens in brand new Win32 project (I only do Win32)
- OS is Win10
- It's not specific to a form/unit
- No plugins installed

Any ideas how to give it life again?

Comment: Does the unit you're currently working on go with a form? If so, is  `{R *.dfm}` in the code? If not, the IDE doesn't know that there's a form/unit to switch to and from, and the buttons wouldn't be enabled. It's difficult with the new IDE appearance to tell when buttons are enabled or not, because some of them are poorly designed. Do you have the same problem with a new, empty VCL forms application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by:

Toolbar (Right-Click) > Customize > View checkBox (The last one)
Then click Reset button on the top right

[image]

Comment: This is much quicker than using my own answer. I have moved the 'correct answer' marker to yours.

Answer (score 6):

This is the trick to fix the issue:

- Right-click on the toolbar and choose *Customize...*. Go to the Commands tab
- Drag those four icons that don't work from the toolbar into the Commands window. **Remember which they are** (maybe make a screenshot first)
  (They **were already there** and dragging them off the toolbar did not change anything)
- Drag them back from the Commands window onto the toolbar

Comment: It;'s remarkable that I have to search back for my own SO post because it happened again two years later (Now Delphi Alexandria 11)